# If static methods cannot be overriden, why must they satisfy the exception throws contract of the static method in the parent?

Tags: java, inheritance, static

Since static functions belong to a class, they are inherited but not overridden, merely hidden. From the code below, it seems that the woof method in B can only have a "throws IOException" declaration if the parent method also has it. I.e the below code gives a compiler error that the throws clause is not compatible with the one in A.woof 
If the method is not being overridden, why must it satisfy the exception contract ?

```
class A {
    static void woof()  { //Compiles IF i add throws IOException here
        System.out.println("A's woof");
    }
}

class B extends A {
    static void woof() throws IOException {  //Compiler error
        System.out.println("B's woof");
    }
```

Comment: It is worth noting that the compiler says *"overridden method does not throw IOException"* and not *"hidden method does not throw IOException"*.

Comment: You can override a method with less exceptions than the method of the super class, but you can't introduce new ones. look up the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56860/what-is-the-liskov-substitution-principle)

Comment: @MadMatts LSP applies to subtyping; this isn't subtyping.

Comment: Perhaps this has to do with the fact that you *can* call static methods on an object instead of the class.

Comment: @AndyTurner If this was possible and you had `A a = new B(); ((B)a).woof();` you'd get an IOException where you wouldn't with `a.woof()`. Does this not break the principle?

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour has been captured in the JLS spec. Looks like the overriding and hiding methods are treated the same way by compiler.

> More precisely, suppose that B is a class or interface, and A is a
>   superclass or superinterface of B, and a method declaration m2 in B
>   overrides or hides a method declaration m1 in A. Then:
>
> If m2 has a
>   throws clause that mentions any checked exception types, then m1 must
>   have a throws clause, or a compile-time error occurs.
>
> For every
>   checked exception type listed in the throws clause of m2, that same
>   exception class or one of its supertypes must occur in the erasure
>   (§4.6) of the throws clause of m1; otherwise, a compile-time error
>   occurs.
>
> If the unerased throws clause of m1 does not contain a
>   supertype of each exception type in the throws clause of m2 (adapted,
>   if necessary, to the type parameters of m1), a compile-time unchecked
>   warning occurs.